# Selecting default item from Combobox C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have few items on my `ComboBox` items collection, and i'd like to select one item from this list and set it as default item - when app starts - this item is already on `comboBox`.

I'm trying something like that:

```
SelectPrint11.SelectedIndex=2;
```

but error is:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: InvalidArgument=Value of '2' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'
```

Edit:

In `mylist` are 3 items, `Printer1`, `Printer2`, `Printer3`. All are added in `ComboBox Properties -> Items -> Collection`

Comment: Are you sure, that there are **three** (!) items in your ComboBox when that code is executed?

Comment: Try using **comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.Items.Count - 1;**

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can set using **SelectedIndex**

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex= 1;
```

OR

**SelectedItem**

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem = "your value"; //
```

The latter won't throw an exception if the value is not available in the combobox

*EDIT*

If the value to be selected is not specific then you would be better off with this

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.Items.Count - 1;
```

Comment: if you are using the `SelectedIndex` property, the count starts at 0, not 1.

Comment: or 

`comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf("itemName");`

Answer (score 8):

Remember that collections in C# are zero-based (in other words, the **first** item in a collection is at position **zero**). If you have two items in your list, and you want to select the last item, use `SelectedIndex = 1`.

Answer (score 3):

```
private void comboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 Combobox.selectedIndex= your index;
}
```

OR if you want to display some value after comparing into combobox

```
 foreach (var item in comboBox.Items)
            {
                if (item.ToString().ToLower().Equals("your item in lower"))
                {
                    comboBox.SelectedValue = item;
                }
            }
```

I hope it will help, it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

This means that your selectedindex is out of the range of the array of items in the combobox.  The array of items in your combo box is **zero-based**, so if you have 2 items, it's item 0 and item 1.

Answer (score 2):

this is the correct form:

```
comboBox1.Text = comboBox1.Items[0].ToString();
```

U r welcome

Answer (score 0):

first, go to the form load where your comboBox is located,

then try this code

comboBox1.SelectedValue = 0; //shows the 1st item in your collection

Answer (score -1):

```
    ComboBox1.Text = ComboBox1.Items(0).ToString
```

This code is show you Combobox1 first item in Vb.net

Comment: ComboBox1.Text = ComboBox1.Items(0).ToString();

Comment: Was specific in the C# request. Helpful for some, but does not answer the question.