# Why am I getting null from a class C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am sending a variable to a class, and while the program is debugging, when I send the variable, if I'm going to see the class, there's the value in the variable, but when I need to use it, I'm getting null, here is what I'm doing:

```
Clase1 objclase = new Clase1();

private void b_Aceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //cbnombre is the name of a combobox
    objclase.retornaNombre(cb_nombre.SelectedItem.ToString());
    //MessageBox.Show(cb_nombre.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

The class has:

```
public class Clase1
{
    public string _nombre;
    public string nombre
    {
        get { return _nombre; }
        set { _nombre = value; }
    }

    public void retornaNombre(string nom)
    {
        _nombre = nom;
    }
}
```

And here is my problem:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frm_IngresarNombre ventana = new frm_IngresarNombre();
    ventana.ShowDialog();

    MessageBox.Show(objclase.nombre);
}
```

At this messagebox I'm getting null...
Hope you can help me.

Comment: You have not set the property and accessing the same and thats why getting error.

Comment: See [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/) on non-english code.

Comment: Teh question is mostly: 1.) is the objclase the same as in the other function.  2.) does the be_aceptar method get run BEFORE button1_click?     if both are true then its strange but I would guess that one of the two is false

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking for debugging help.

Comment: easiest explanation would be, you get the strings default value of <null>. did you assign anything to nombre before accessing it? And why do you build a method to assign something to nombre if you can access it directly?

Comment: Add System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(cb_nombre.SelectedItem.ToString()); below objclase.retornaNombre(cb_nombre.SelectedItem.ToString());  and see the output in Outputwindow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you have imitate the class while click the button ? If not there will throw null reference exception in addonal change

```
   `public string _nombre;
    public string nombre
    {
        get { return _nombre; }
        set { _nombre = value; }
    }`
```

to

```
    private string _nombre;
    public string nombre
    {
        get { return _nombre; }
        set { _nombre = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the get/set method you created, you don't actually need the assignment method you wrote.

you can assign a variable to your object by simply writing 
`objclase.nombre = value` rather than needing an assignment method  (get/set works in this fashion, but also doubles as an accessor too).

As you are assigning the variable from a selected item, I expect the item you believe to be selected isn't actually selected - I've had issues in the past where the top item is visible, but not considered "selected" thus will also return an incorrect value.

See [Selecting default item from Combobox C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633455/selecting-default-item-from-combobox-c-sharp) with regards to solving that issue