# C# WPF - Combo box - Default with the last selected item

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing an app with C# WPF. I have a Combo box inlcduing around 20 names (first name last name)
The app will be installed on customers computers and they have to select their name in the app and do other things and then close the app. My aim is to set the combo box ina way that when they open next time the app, theire previous name selection is set as the default name in the combo box.
So, first time opening the defult combo box is empty, next time is their last time name selection.
I would appreciate if you could help me.

Best regards,
Alireza

Comment: Have a look at [c# - approach for saving user settings in a WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784477/c-sharp-approach-for-saving-user-settings-in-a-wpf-application)

Comment: what have u tried?

Comment: I tried this, but did not help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633455/selecting-default-item-from-combobox-c-sharp/5633539

Comment: I think, I have to save data somewhere on the local computers and call it back everytime.